# Jquery DataTable with large data sets from multiple Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, datatable

I have a question about the rendering of DataTable with the large data sets (60k). The problem: the data is not from a DB but a API Rest and due to the limit of this API, I have to make many requests to get all the datas (1k results max by request). The backend is PHP.

As I know we can use server side for the large data sets but I can't just get all the results with PHP (limit memory exceeded). And then the performance is critical too.

Can we make it work with DataTable and its normal paging system? I think I got a solution: make a manual paging system, then everytime the user clicks on the page number, a Ajax request will be sent to get the page's content. Is it good or there is a more simple way to do it?

Thanks very much for your helps!

Comment: _"I think I got a solution"_ - Sounds reasonable. You should try it out and i it works as expected, you have your answer. If you run into some specific issue with the code along the way, come back, show us the code and explain the issue. If you just want someone to review your solution when you're done, you can post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's really weird that nobody has this problem before, I can't find many informations about it. Maybe they don't even think about showing the 60k results with a paging system ^^

Comment: _I have to make many requests to get all the datas_ - Right. And that's the point: You don't need to make all those requests all the time, every time. You only need to make the one request that allows you to show 1 page of relevant results to the user (that is, the 1 page of results which are sorted and filtered, as per the user's selections). And once you have that one page, a **well-designed REST API** should let you get the "next" page, and the "7th" page, and the "last" page, and so on...

Comment: @andrewjames: yes you are right, I can make a result set sorted and filtered, and even make a search with API. Just want to know if there is a more simple way with DataTable because his paging system is really good and flexible. I'll try and let you know guys. Thanks

Comment: Understood - yes, you do lose a lot of DataTables functionality when you choose server-side processing. Take a look at [deferred rendering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender). That may help (or it may not help at all). Also, the [infinite scroller](https://datatables.net/blog/2011-06-11) may be of interest - but I have never used it.